# Heroku Local on exit null throws ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL error

Tags: heroku, local

I wanted to set up ENV variables to keep my API keys safe between local and remote Heroku instances. I followed the steps outlined in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

When I run heroku local I get a "Error [ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL]: Unknown signal: null" upon exit. Any clues why I would get this? My app is not at all sophisticated.

```
    [OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
18:35:04 web.1   |  > youtube-channel-watch@1.0.0 start /Users/farhad/Server/code/2017/tommy/youtube-channel-watch
18:35:04 web.1   |  > node app.js
18:35:04 web.1   |  WHAT HAPPENED TO MONDAY? Official Trailer (2017) Noomi Rapace Netflix Movie HD
18:35:04 web.1   |  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POd9-pOCQ7I
18:35:04 web.1   |  MOTHER! Official Trailer Teaser (2017) Jennifer Lawrence Horror Drama Movie HD
18:35:04 web.1   |  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R06aPrUdAtw
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
internal/util.js:183
  throw new errors.Error('ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL', signal);
  ^

Error [ERR_UNKNOWN_SIGNAL]: Unknown signal: null
    at convertToValidSignal (internal/util.js:183:9)
    at ChildProcess.kill (internal/child_process.js:381:5)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/farhad/.local/share/heroku/client/node_modules/foreman/lib/proc.js:54:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/farhad/.local/share/heroku/client/node_modules/foreman/lib/proc.js:50:13)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
```

Comment: It seems it is a Node.js v.8 problem: https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/562

Comment: My node version is v6.11.0. So I don't know if its v8.0

Comment: Have you set it up explicitly in your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in the `@heroku/foreman` package. Make sure you are using `@heroku/foreman` and not `node-foreman`.